# 2d array save python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a program that creates a 2d array in Python but how do I save it as a csv file, it is

```
value_a = int(input("Type in a value for a: "))
value_b = int(input("Now a value for b: "))
value_c = int(input("And a value for c: "))
d = value_a + value_b + value_c
result = [[value_a, value_b, value_c, d]]  # put the initial values into the array
number_of_loops = int(input("type in the number of loops the program must execute: "))  

def loops(a, b, c, n):
    global result
    for i in range(n):
        one_loop = []  # assign an empty array for the result of one loop
        temp_a = a
        a = ((a + 1) * 2) # This adds 1 to a and then multiplies by 2
        one_loop.append(str(a))  
        b = b * 2
        one_loop.append(b)
        c = (temp_a + b)
        one_loop.append(c)
        d = a + b + c
        one_loop.append(d)
        result.append(one_loop)


print(result)
loops(value_a, value_b, value_c, number_of_loops)
print(result)
```

It prints ok but how do I save the array as a csv file

Comment: What have you tried? Python has a built-in csv module that might be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows),

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use third-party libraries and you're going to be working with 2d (or more) arrays in Python, I'd recommend you use a library like numpy or pandas.  Numpy includes a method to write out arrays as csv files called `savetxt`.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with CSV writing and reading functionality.  See  [The Python Standard Library » 13.1csv — CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for fuller documentation, but here is a quick example taken from that page and adapted to your problem:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in results:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```